# android how to create a dynamic central view between header and footer programmatically

Tags: android, view, header, footer

I'm new in android development, so be patience please.
I'm trying to create a simple app with an header (text view and 4 button)and a footer (that contains 2 button and a central seekbar).
I would like to use the button in the header for change programmatically the view in the screen centre but without hiding header and footer. I've read a lot about how to call new activities and use the inflater but I'm just thinking of being such an idiot because Ido not understand the right way to do it!
Somebody can help me?
thanks!